# Jquery tools tabs customization

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-tools, jquery-tabs

i want to do same like it.

we can do tabs easily through jquery(http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/skins.html) but i don't know how to display default content on tab content place.pls look image it will show what i want exactly.

please any one help and give idea to do.

Comment: A ready-made plugin comes with certain limitations. If you want this much of customization, I'd suggest you to do the tabs yourself. It's not a hard thing, if you're familiar with jQuery and CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a **fiddle** here: http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/cfmvE/

Should get you started in the right direction. If you want to use jQuery UI tabs, take a look at the million examples around the internet. However, what your trying to do is very simple and can be achieved easily with the attached fiddle. It's very easy to add ajax into the code.

```
<div id="tab_container">
    <div class="tab_content tab_1 tab_active">
        What's your name?<br/><br/>
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="tab_content tab_2">
        Some other question
    </div>
    <div class="tab_content tab_3">
        A final question blah
    </div>        
</div>

<div id="tabs">
    <a href="#" tab="1">Question 1</a>
    <a href="#" tab="2">Question 2</a>
    <a href="#" tab="3">Question 3</a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#tabs > a').click(function() {
    var $tab = $('.tab_' + $(this).attr('tab'));
    if ($tab.length)
    {
        // Hide active tab & selected style:
        $('.tab_active').removeClass('tab_active');
        $('#tabs .active').removeClass('active');

        // Show clicked tab content
        $tab.addClass('tab_active');

        // Set tab styling
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

CSS available on the fiddle.

---

**Edit:**

Here's another **fiddle** demonstrating tabs using just HTML using the hyperlink anchor trick. Javascript not required: http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/6e2w5/

Comment: thanks for your great help dude. have u looked my screen shot? i want tabs same like that. please give any idea for set main div behind tabs content.

Comment: Well that is all about utilising the z-index CSS property. See: http://www.quackit.com/css/properties/css_z-index.cfm -- just as a side note, we'll help point you in the right direction, or with any code you need to understand, but we won't write this for you -- it's not that kind of site ;-)